# html fixed position IE issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a chat button/link that sits at the bottom right of my page. This is my code in the css, it works perfect in firefox and chrome:

```
a.trigger{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px; right: 15px;
padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
display: block;
}
```

In IE though, it just sits at the top of the page. How can I fix it so it works in IE too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: IE7, IE8 and IE9 support the fixed value only if a `!DOCTYPE` is specified.

The first line of your page should one of the following:

HTML 4

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

HTML 5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a clever way to make IE behave a little better. Make sure the css is in that order and that should be the answer or at least get you closer to your goal.

```
* html .sticky {
  position:absolute;
}

.sticky {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:40%;
}
```

Comment: Ouch. That's a horrid hack. Still, IE is a horrid browser. +1

Comment: when a browser is made from sticks and mud, you have to maintain it with sticks and mud :( hope it helped!